# Make JComboBox behave like a menu with subdivisions

Tags: java, swing, menu, jcombobox

I want to be able to subdivide the options in a JComboBox (it's a fairly extensive list, maybe 14 elements or so), and render the options menu-style.

For example, I'd want the dropdown menu from the JComboBox to be Dog, Cat, and Bird. When the user moves the mouse over the option "Dog" I want a menu to pop up to the right of the dropdown with the options "Beagle", "Poodle", and "Labrador". This way, the user won't see the huge list at the same time. This should behave like a menu.

Can I do this? If not via some API, via some kind of hack?

Comment: Ahh thanks @Andrew Thompson I forgot the swing tag

Comment: The point is that the user won't want to parse through a 14-element long list unless it's subdivided.

Comment: *"the user won't want to parse through a 14-element long list"*  I disagree, but ..well you know your users better than I do.

Comment: Try taking a look at [**this**](http://www.jroller.com/santhosh/entry/jcombobox_items_with_separators) for a start of a possible solution

Comment: What's wrong with a JMenu? You could have it appear on right-click.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual approach in this case is to have Dog, Cat & Bird in one combo, and another combo. for the sub-types that is populated according to the selection in the first combo.  E.G.

[image: PetSelector]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import javax.swing.*;

class PetSelector {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JPanel gui = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,1,5,5));

                String[] speciesName = { "Dog", "Cat", "Bird"};
                final String[][] breedName = {
                    {"Basenji", "Pomeranian", "Alsation"},
                    {"Burmese", "Persian", "Siamese"},
                    {"DoDo", "Archeopteryx", "Pheonix"}
                };
                final JComboBox petSpecies = new JComboBox(speciesName);
                final JComboBox petBreed = new JComboBox();
                ItemListener speciesListener = new ItemListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                        int ii = petSpecies.getSelectedIndex();
                        ComboBoxModel cbm = new DefaultComboBoxModel(breedName[ii]);
                        petBreed.setModel(cbm);
                        petBreed.requestFocusInWindow();
                    }
                };
                petSpecies.addItemListener(speciesListener);
                gui.add(petSpecies);
                gui.add(petBreed);

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, gui);
            }
        };
        // Swing GUIs should be created and updated on the EDT
        // http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```